# plot the mean of grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i tried the following code on a multiindexed dataframe:
    data.header =['name', 'pH', 'salt', 'id']
    for grp,val in data.df.groupby(level = data.header):

```
    print(val['concentration'])
```

and i get the output:

```
name    pH   salt  id
sample  7.5  50    1     0.229230
                   1     0.230369
```

actually i would like to have the aggregated mean:

```
name    pH   salt  id
sample  7.5  50    1     0.2298
```

following code does not work `print(val['concentration'].apply(lambda x: x.mean()))` or `print(val['concentration'].aggregate(np.mean)`

I can do:

```
for grp, val in data.df.groupby(level=data.header[0:-1])['concentration']:
#print(val)
plt.plot(val,'o')
```

and i get (which is pretty close to what i would like to have):

[image]

but still i would like to aggregate the group first and calculate the mean. Secondly i would like to plot only those rows with the index 'sample'

The data frame: [enter link description here](https://bokubox.boku.ac.at/#ddd6e4cdfa24ca85e5ff3812d5cda192)

Any suggestions how to do that ?

Comment: Can you provide some example input data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this solution works:

```
df = data.df.groupby(level=data.header).aggregate(np.mean).copy()
```

and from here on i can do the desired plots etc.

```
for grp, val in df.groupby(level=data.header[0:-1])['concentration']:
    #print(val)
    plt.plot(val,'o')
```